# SQL Server : case when in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can you teach me what am I doing wrong in my case? :)

I am selecting invoices and repayments.

**Error**:

> Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
>   An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'end'.

Code:

```
select 
    I.subject1, R.subject2
from
    dbo.invoice I
left join 
    dbo.repayments R on I.subject1 = R.subject2
where
    case
       when R.subject2 is not null and R.remains_due > 0 
          then R.remains_due
       when R.subject2 is not null and R.remains_due = 0 
          then I.remains_due
       when R.subject2 is not null and R.due_date <= GETDATE() 
          then R.due_date
       when R.subject2 is null and I.due_date <= GETDATE() 
          then I.due_date
    end
```

Comment: It's generally a better idea to use `AND`/`OR` instead of `case` expressions in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Your case expression returns a value, now you need to compare it with something.

Comment: I need "case" because "then" is important to me.
The compare you said? Could you tell me more about it?

Comment: You probably don't need "then" at all... Yes, your case expression returns a value. What to do with it?

Comment: Then how can i tell the program to grab specific attribute without "then" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following show how to use search conditions in the `WHERE clause`.

```
SELECT
  ColumnB,
  ColumnA
FROM
  TableA
WHERE
  ColumnA =  CASE WHEN ColumnB IS NULL THEN 'Test AA'
                  WHEN ColumnB IS NOT NULL THEN 'Test BB'
                  ELSE 'Test CC' END
```

Your query is not correct. Query looks like:

```
SELECT
  ColumnB,
  ColumnA
FROM
  TableA
WHERE
  -- Where is ColumnA???
  -- Return types must be same type!
  CASE WHEN ColumnB IS NULL THEN 'Test AA' -- VARCHAR?
       WHEN ColumnB IS NOT NULL THEN 1 -- INT ?
       ELSE '2016.10.20' END -- DATETIME?
```

**Updated**

```
select 
    I.subject1, 
    R.subject2
from
    dbo.invoice I LEFT join 
    dbo.repayments R on I.subject1 = R.subject2
WHERE
     (
        R.subject2 is not NULL AND
        R.remains_due >= 0  AND
        R.due_date <= GETDATE() 
     ) OR
     (
        R.subject2 is NULL AND
        I.due_date <= GETDATE() AND
        I.remains_due >= 0
      )
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply ! :)

Comment: Column remains_due is money and column due date is datetime.
Should I convert it into the varchar for example?

I am not sure if I completely understand what you replied.

Comment: Which invoces you want to select?

Comment: I want to select all invoices where remains due is > 0 and invoices after the due date. Here comes to play repayments. When repayment exists and remains due on it is > 0 then I am interrested on due date in repayment, not in invoice.

If it is not clear, ask me. I will try to give you all the information I have. :)

Comment: It gives me > 12k records :/ OMG, I will kill myself... It is not possible because we cannot have so many invoices after the due date :/

Comment: @j.doe Question is not clear. Can you show sample and expected data?

Comment: Bro, I put a screen to your answer.

Comment: @j.doe Result looks like correct. What is wrong in result? Show me please.

Comment: You are right. Results are correct. I was confused that our company has more than 10k invoices after the due date :/ I will ask my guru and I will reply what he tells me. Many thanks !

Comment: My guru told me that it is correct ! He told me that he wanted to use CASE statement because we will use it in a template in our CRM system.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
select 
    I.subject1, R.subject2
from
    dbo.invoice I
left join 
    dbo.repayments R on I.subject1 = R.subject2
where

       R.subject2 is not null and R.remains_due > 0 
          AND
        R.subject2 is not null and R.remains_due = 0 
          AND
        R.subject2 is not null and R.due_date <= GETDATE() 
          AND
        R.subject2 is null and I.due_date <= GETDATE() ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a total misunderstanding of the WHERE clause.  The where clause is a condition of WHAT RECORDS TO BE INCLUDED in the result set.  Ex: Give me all records where an invoice is >= some date range, or an invoice where an amount = some value you are looking for.  These need to return a logical TRUE or FALSE ONLY.

Using the case statement would be in your field list to identify which VALUE you want back based on the condition.  In this case, under the specific conditions of the row you want something specific returned to show the user.

```
select 
      I.subject1, 
      R.subject2,
      case when R.subject2 is not null and R.remains_due > 0 
              then R.remains_due
           when R.subject2 is not null and R.remains_due = 0 
              then I.remains_due
           end  as AmountDue,
      case when R.subject2 is not null and R.due_date <= GETDATE() 
              then R.due_date
           when R.subject2 is null and I.due_date <= GETDATE() 
              then I.due_date
           end   DueDate
   from
      dbo.invoice I
         left join dbo.repayments R 
            on I.subject1 = R.subject2
```

Answer (score 1):

The basically use of CASE EXPRESSION is - evaluate some expression, based on the result of expression return the **Single Value**

Now you almost did correct in WHERE clause. Case Expression returning some values but in WHERE clause that values are need to be compare with some other values and this is missing part in your query . You can try this way as well to get correct result.

```
...
where 
1 = case
      when R.subject2 is not null and R.remains_due > 0 
         then 1
      when R.subject2 is not null and R.remains_due = 0 
         then 1
      when R.subject2 is not null and R.due_date <= GETDATE() 
         then 1
      when R.subject2 is null and I.due_date <= GETDATE() 
        then 1
   end
```

Comment: Thank you, 1 = case is cool. But your code gave me 0,5 m records :X